# Invisible Remote Resources Window on Macbook Pro

Tags: mac, remote-desktop, macbook-pro

I am currently configuring a new MBP(13-inch, Early 2015, OSX 10.11.6). With our macs, we use Remote Resources in the Microsoft Remote Desktop app (V 8.0.33) for our custom ERP software. All of the apps open fine with no problems, except 1. When I attempt to open it, the login window comes up, I login, then nothing happens. Along the toolbar at the top, it shows that the window exists. If I swipe up on the mac to see all the open windows, it is there but invisible. I have altered the resolution, uninstalled and wiped out plist's related to the app, and even wiped the drive and reinstalled OSX. Still having the same issue.

I did discover that if I have an active session on a different PC or mac for whatever user is trying to bring up this window, and then take over the session, it works without issue. It is only when a new session is being created from this computer specifically. I have also verified that it works on other macs with the same app version and OSX. Unfortunately I do not have another of the same model and size mac to test on.

I've run out of ideas and could really use assistance.

Comment: Did you try on a Windows PC to see if the same thing happens? This would help isolate the problem to either the client or the server.

Comment: Tried on Windows and on other Macs. Works fine. I can also take over the session on this specific computer and it works fine. Its only when it is creating a new session for this specific app.